# Could not choose appropriate plugin: The nginx plugin is not working;

Tags: nginx, certbot

---

### Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/api.shunhinggaoke.com.conf

Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
Could not choose appropriate plugin: The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError()
Attempting to renew cert (api.shunhinggaoke.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/api.shunhinggaoke.com.conf produced an unexpected error: The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError(). Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.shunhinggaoke.com/fullchain.pem (failure)

---

** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.shunhinggaoke.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry

### **          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)

1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

Answer (score 7):

Check certbot-nginx plugin is installed first.

apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx solved the similar issue in my Debian.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across your question and don't know if you still have the issue. You need to post more details. You don't even indicate on which platform you have the problem. I assume it's on a Linux machine. If so, are you running the `certbot renew --dry-run` command from the command line or from a cron script?

The problem above indicates an environment problem, most likely a PATH issue and I assume you only get this when running the script via cron. I also assume that you added it to your crontab using the `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e` command.

The solution commonly proposed is to set your PATH in the crontab file itself and try again. That means, don't do a `(sudo) crontab -e` but make sure that either your system crontab in the /etc/crontab file has it set or you set it in the crontab file for certbot.

For me on Ubuntu 16.04 it's /etc/crond.d/certbot and it looks like this:

```
#lots of commented lines preceding ...
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew
```

It runs twice a day. You can test it by adding another line like this:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet --dry-run
```

and then watch your certbot log. It's probably in /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log and read protected. Do a

```
sudo tail -f  /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
```

and see what you get. You should get `no renewal failures` at the end of the run if it works ok. The script runs every minute so turn it off after you got the logs.

Comment: Upvoting for PATH hint

Comment: Just add PATH hint and it works on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74171106) is more precise.