# Could not find a usable 'nginx' binary. Ensure nginx exists, the binary is executable

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, certificate

I'm trying to install certbot on my digital ocean droplet. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and following instructions from https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx.

The error occurs when I run `sudo certbot --nginx`. The error I get is:

```
The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError("Could not find a usable 'nginx' binary. 
Ensure nginx exists, the binary is executable, and your PATH is set correctly.")
```

This is my first time using digital ocean and such so please explain the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use options to specify the path to the 'nginx' binary and conf directory (it seems that certbot expects `nginx.conf` file in nginx's installation directory if you do not specify it manually)

```
certbot certonly --nginx --nginx-ctl /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx --nginx-server-root /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf
```

Comment: Certbot 0.31.0 on Debian Buster on GCP, I had to specify --nginx-ctl /usr/sbin/nginx

Comment: @Jerther thank you, it worked for me on CentOS 7 and nginx was probably installed from Epel.  First `which nginx` and used that returned path: ` --nginx-ctl /usr/sbin/nginx` I will add this as an answer.

Comment: On debian 12 it's:
`certbot --nginx --nginx-ctl /usr/sbin/nginx --nginx-server-root /etc/nginx/`

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem on CentOS 7 and Nginx was probably installed from Epel.
Renew was working from command line but not from cronjob. I found this in letsencrypt logs: **`Could not find a usable 'nginx' binary`**

So I tried what @Jerther said in a comment, specified `--nginx-ctl`. First I got the nginx path with: `which nginx` then I used that returned path `/usr/sbin/nginx` in the crontab command.

So in my crontab I replaced:

`/usr/bin/certbot renew`

with

`/usr/bin/certbot --nginx-ctl /usr/sbin/nginx renew`

Answer (score 2):

looks like theres problem with certbot snap package, you can try to remove it from snap, and install certbot again with apt.

you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't help me as my certbot was installed correctly when I upgraded from Ubuntu 18. I did, however, manage to get more useful debugging information by running the following command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/certbot renew --nginx --debug-challenges -v
```

If the output of that is too verbose then remove the `-v` at the end, either way it should give you much better insight as to what the root cause of the error is.

Comment: Good idea to run certbot renew manually to see the cause of the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much @Jerther and @adrianTNT,

That fixed the problem! I've change

> certbot --nginx-ctl /usr/sbin/nginx renew

instead of

> certbot renew --nginx

CentOs 7
Renew was working from command line but not from cronjob, now it works!